# Access 2010 form suddenly putting new entries at the top of my backend table instead of the bottom?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I don't know why this glitch is happening.  I'm using a form to populate a backend table.  All of a sudden it randomly adds the new entries from the form at the top row of the backend.  Why would this be occurring?
This is frustrating as my form is designed to take the last measurement from the last entry (`=DLast("entry","BackEndTable")`) and put it as default in the fresh form.  Now because it has decided to put new entries at the top of the table, the last entry stays the same and the default value in the fresh form stays the same (which then is wrong and needs to be changed manually).
Why would this be happening?
How might I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table and any keys it might have which could be causing this?  Are there any keys which are being set which would set them to show at the top?

Comment: Could this be happening because you ordered your data ascending/descending?

Comment: I have no key and I recently set the filter by smallest to largest but that did not help so I set it back.  Therefore no filters or sort when problem first arose.  Dmax will not work as a long term solution as I have various categories with "From" and "To" depths for each of those categories.  As soon as I enter a new category, my "to" would default to be the dmax of the highest From, which would be incorrect in the new category as it will have a different set of ranges.  So need to have the records from the form going in order of entry and populating that way in the backend I think.

Comment: Is there a way to set a key to be created by the order the form records are entered?

Comment: Gabe3886, something is going awry for sure as for some reason and I can't identify the trigger yet, the next record in a form will show up at the top of the back end.  Then my attempts to create new records all show the  last "To" in the back end in my fresh record's "from" instead of the last form entry.  Dmax default in the "From" works when I have only one set of depth ranges, but as soon as I have more than one, this will stop working.  Like to get to the reason the form is seemingly randomly placing new records haphazardly rather than at the bottom of my back end.  Must be needing a key.

Answer (score 0):

Use DMax.

DFirst and DLast only returns some random record - could be the "first" or "last", but you never know.

> how would one go about making an "ORDER BY clause"

Sounds like you need to read up SQL and query design in Access. You can bing/Google on that.

Here it could be:

```
Select * From BackEndTable Order By LogDate
```

where LogDate is your time field for the Measurement.

Comment: Yes it is random.  How can I get it to use Dlast from the last record in the table instead of random?  Dmax is not a long term solution as I will have different categories with "From" and "To" therefore dmax will only work for the first category's From and To as by the second Category the From and To would be defaulting to the dmax of the first category rather than a continuation of the category now being worked on.

Comment: I found this on http://codevba.com/msaccess/dlookup_data_retrieval.htm#.VTqpUSFVhBc :  

DFirst and DLast

These functions return the value of a specified field in the first or last record, respectively, of the result set returned by a query that includes an ORDER BY. For tables the returned value will be random.

Warning
If the query does not include an ORDER BY clause, the values returned will be arbitrary because records are usually returned in no particular order.

Comment: "If the query does not include an ORDER BY clause"  
  
So I guess in order to use dlast I need an Order By clause in my table (or does it have to be a query?)  If it has to be a query then that might mean user would have to run the query before they clicked the arrow to go to a new record in the form?  That wouldn't be practical, so not sure if that would work.  Assuming it can be ran from a table, how would one go about making an "ORDER BY clause"

Comment: I added this to the answer above.